# Java - Get log file from a server

Tags: java, server

I have a Java Application and want to read in a log file. But this log file be located on a intern Server.

I want to get this file ( like WinSCP ) from the server to my Application and read the file data in. How can I do this ?

Comment: You can copy it, unless something is preventing you.

Comment: You could also write a web service that serves up the log files via a GET method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an SSH library like [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

and do something like [scp from example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java.html)

HTH,

Gal